# How to preload a webview with uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios

I need to present a webview in every page with a **uipageviewcontroller**.Every page is a tableview, and the webview is a property of tableviewcell.

Now the problem is:

there is a delay when turning a page, because it's time-consuming to load a webview and present it. So I want to eliminate this delay by preload webview. I know that uipageviewcontroller preload  prior and next tableviewcontroller to the current one, but it only load their view to memory.

So cells, not to mention their property, webview in my case, are not created until tableviewdatasource methods are called. So how to preload these webviews without changing given view architecture? Or is there a better way with just a little change to the given architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView manages the cell lifecycle and position when cells are rendered onscreen. What are you trying to achieve here is something that the UITableView was not designed to accommodate.

In my opinion, there’s only one thing to do: throw out UITableView and start your own TableView from scratch (see below example) :

```
@protocol TableViewDataSource <NSObject>

- (NSInteger) numberOfRows;
- (UIView *) cellForRow:(NSInteger) row;
- (void) itemAdded;
- (void) itemAddedAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end 

@interface TableView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;

// the object that acts as the data source for this table
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TableViewDataSource> datasource;

// the UIScrollView that hosts the table contents
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) UIScrollView* scrollView;

-(UIView*) dequeueReusableCell;
-(NSArray*) visibleCells;

// forces the table to dispose of all the cells and re-build the table.
-(void) reloadData;
-(void) registerClassForCells: (Class)cellClass;

@end

const float ROW_HEIGHT = 50.0f;

@implementation TableView
{
    UIScrollView* _scrollView;
    id<TableViewDataSource> _datasource;

    // a set of cells which are re-useable
    NSMutableSet* _reuseCells;

    // the Class which indicates the cell type
    Class _cellClass;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
        [self addSubview:_scrollView];

        _scrollView.delegate = self;
        _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        _reuseCells = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    _scrollView.frame = self.frame;
    [self refreshView];
}

#pragma mark - cell lifecycle

-(void) refreshView
{
    if (CGRectIsNull(_scrollView.frame))
    {
        return;
    }

     _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.bounds.size.width, [_datasource numberOfRows] * ROW_HEIGHT);

    for(UIView* cell in [self cellSubviews])
    {
        if (cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height < _scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        {
            [self recycleCell:cell];
        }

        if (cell.frame.origin.y > _scrollView.contentOffset.y + _scrollView.frame.size.height)
        {
            [self recycleCell:cell];
        }
    }

    int firstVisibleIndex = MAX(0, floor(_scrollView.contentOffset.y / ROW_HEIGHT));
    int lastVisibleIndex = MIN([_datasource numberOfRows],
                               firstVisibleIndex + 1 + ceil(_scrollView.frame.size.height / ROW_HEIGHT));

    for (int row =  firstVisibleIndex; row < lastVisibleIndex; row++)
    {
        UIView* cell = [self cellForRow:row];
        if (!cell)
        {
            UIView* cell = [_datasource cellForRow:row];
            float topEdgeForRow = row * ROW_HEIGHT;
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, topEdgeForRow, _scrollView.frame.size.width, ROW_HEIGHT);
            [_scrollView insertSubview:cell atIndex:0];
        }
    }
}

-(void) recycleCell:(UIView*)cell
{
    [_reuseCells addObject:cell];
    [cell removeFromSuperview];
}

-(UIView*) cellForRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    float topEdgeForRow = row * SHC_ROW_HEIGHT;
    for(UIView* cell in [self cellSubviews])
    {
        if (cell.frame.origin.y == topEdgeForRow)
        {
            return cell;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

-(NSArray*)cellSubviews
{
    NSMutableArray* cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(UIView* subView in _scrollView.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[SHCTableViewCell class]])
        {
            [cells addObject:subView];
        }
    }
    return cells;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate handlers

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self refreshView];

    // forward the delegate method
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)]){
        [self.delegate scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }

}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate forwarding

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}


- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        return self.delegate;
    }
    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}

#pragma mark - public API methods

-(void) registerClassForCells: (Class)cellClass
{
    _cellClass = cellClass;
}

-(NSArray*) visibleCells
{
    NSMutableArray* cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(UIView* subView in [self cellSubviews])
    {
        [cells addObject:subView];
    }
    NSArray* sortedCells = [cells sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        UIView* view1 = (UIView*)obj1;
        UIView* view2 = (UIView*)obj2;

        float result = view2.frame.origin.y - view1.frame.origin.y;
        if (result > 0.0) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if (result < 0.0){
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }
    }];

    return sortedCells;
}

-(UIView*)dequeueReusableCell
{
    // first obtain a cell from the re-use pool
    UIView* cell = [_reuseCells anyObject];
    if (cell) {
        [_reuseCells removeObject:cell];
    }

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[_cellClass alloc] init];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)reloadData
{
    // remove all subviews
    [[self cellSubviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [self refreshView];
}

#pragma mark - property getters / setters

- (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return _scrollView;
}

-(id<TableViewDataSource>)datasource
{
    return _datasource;
}

-(void)setDatasource:(id<TableViewDataSource>)datasource
{
    _datasource = datasource;
    [self refreshView];
}

@end
```

Comment: Great, Man! It's really a good approach! But I come up with another method: I preload cells for tableviews, when cellForRow is called ,the preloaded cell is supplied, so I don't need to creat cells hurrily. But it's in a way that costs memory.

Answer (score 0):

Preload webview in pageviewcontroller delegate method

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

In pageviewcontroller delegate method you need to find the direction and if it's next then load next to next viewcontroller and release previous to prevous viewcontroller. For e.g. You have page1, page2, page3, page4, page5, page6, page7. Let say you are shown two pages in landscape then load web view for page1, page2, page3 and page4 when pageviewcontroller intialise.

In delegate method check direction if next then load page5 and page6's webview. Show on screen you will have page3 and page4. When you got to page4 and page5 load next 2 page and release page1 and page2.

So just keep immediate previous and next viewcontroller.Release other view controller that will help you for your question and also mange memory so performance would be good as well.

Comment: I can't load webview in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, because cells haven't been created at that time. So the webview to load is nil.

Comment: Are you loading different viewcontroller or view for each page.

Comment: So load view's as process I suggested in answer load page3 and page 4 when page 1 and page2 are visible.

Comment: preload in pageviewcontroller delegate method func pageViewController(UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted: Bool)
Called after a gesture-driven transition completes.

Comment: UIPageViewController can help load prior an next VC to the current one. My tableview controller is sure loaded, but cells are not created. So, I still can't get prepared with my webview.

Comment: For UIPageViewController we need to handle that mechanism on our own. UITableView does this for us.

Comment: There is two methods:     - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController            and - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController    to help preload VC. UITableView is load actually into memory, but the problem is cell not created.((((( I'm not sure you get the point or not.

Comment: Yes, here you can load next and previous views in viewControlerAfter and viewControllerBefore respectively.

Comment: I did have loaded them! But not along with cells...  so I can load vc, but can't load webview...

Comment: Need to understand structure of your view. Please can you share structure of you view.

Comment: Of course.  I use pagecontrollerdatasource to provide pages to pageviewcontroller, each page is a UITableviewcontroller. Each tableview with just one cell, each cell with a property : webview.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: ohk yes that makes sense. So I think that will be UITablecontroller reponsility to load webview. So intial few visible webview will take time. Welcome:)

Comment: Is there any way to manually load uitableviewcells? For e.g, call the cellForRow method actively, not wait for the system's call.

Comment: Yes you can call cellForRow. As we call other methods with use of table's object. For e.g. [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexpath:[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]];